# Dynamic Apache site with route 53 and cloud front not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am beginner with [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) and need some help for my first project .Below is the architecture of my environment and the code runs great on Godaddy .I am trying to move it on AWS. Please try to understand things are working but not in a way that I want.

**Setup**

1. Two private subnet AWS linux servers(like one in Associate practise lab)
2. One S3 bucket mapped to `/var/www/html` sync aws s3 sync cronjob
3. Route53 domain name registered sample.com
4. Cloudfront created https://sample.cloufront.net
5. Application load balancer internet facing --ssl (80,443 listener ports )
6. ACM -SSL certificate issued *.sample.com ,WWW.sample.com
7. RDS instance with everything configured for SG etc

**Issues**

Below are the Issues

1. As soon as I use http -https redirection  from httpd.conf as suggested by Amazon guys I get a bad gateway using [this documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/)
2. Images are not getting delivered by Cloudfront. I tried to redirect in .htaccess getting access denied although I created identity and updated bucket policy .
3. Load Balancer DNS name gets exposed even when route53 mapped to load balancer
4. httpd.conf "All" has been used for override
5. S3 Sync with /var/www/html is changing the permission on linux when any new file is uploaded .

Comment: Cloudfront created with two origins one with load balancer and other with s3 bucket

Comment: You don't need Cloudfront for redirection as you are using apache. You can do anything under apache2 config.
Just make changes in httpd.conf (Apache config) use https://www.tecmint.com/install-free-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-for-apache-on-debian-and-ubuntu/ for installation.

Comment: I have may suggestions how you can overcome with this issue